# Tensorflow Estimator input function for live video inference

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the tf.estimator.Estimator class to train a neural network feeding it images and labels using the TFRecordDataset.

All this is working fine.

Now I'm trying to do predictions from live frames from a webcam. I did another input function for it and it works fine but it's really slow. During the training stage, I'm going through about 100 images/s. The inference code below takes multiple seconds per frame.

I'm thinking, maybe I should rework my input function so it's somehow returning a never ending dataset that returns frame after frame from the live feed.

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Here's what I have now:

```py
def live_input_fn():
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    frame = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(frame, dtype=tf.float32)
    frame = tf.image.per_image_standardization(frame)

    frame = tf.reshape(frame, [1, 120, 160, 3])
    dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(frame)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    features = iterator.get_next()
    return features, None

toy_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=script_dir + "/cnn_tflayers")

while True:
    predictions = toy_classifier.predict(
        input_fn=live_input_fn
    )
    for p in predictions:
        print(label_names[p["classes"]])
        print(p["probabilities"])
```

Comment: why not just pass numpy array to predict?

Comment: You mean without creating the dataset and just return frame, None?